# search strings google

Tags: c#, search

How do you enter a search string into Google and then see how many results it gets? I've tried doing this:

```
string uri = "http://google.com/search?q=" + stringsToSearchFor[0];
string response = wc.UploadString (uri, stringsToSearchFor[0]);
Console.WriteLine ("Response: " + response);
Console.ReadKey (true);
```

I figured the string response would get relevant information such as how many results there are, but when I run the program, I get this error message: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

Comment: Why are you doing both POST and GET request?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more comfortable and easier to use the [Google API.](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest?hl=de)

There you get the results as string. No more need to filter the input / web page for infos.

If you really want to do it via getting the html coded page, use

```
var response = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?q="+mySearchString);
```

Before using the WebClient Class you have to import the namespace:

```
using System.Net;
```

But remember:

If the search string contains whitespaces you have to replace them with '%20'.

To do so, use the `String.Replace`-Function.

```
searchString.Replace(" ","%20");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
string uri = "http://google.com/search?q=" + stringsToSearchFor[0];
string response = wc.UploadString (uri, stringsToSearchFor[0]);
```

to

```
string uri = "http://google.com/search?q=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(stringsToSearchFor[0]);
string response = wc.DownloadString(uri);
```

and It will work...